# singleScrollChildView in flutter not working and screen is not responsive

Tags: flutter, dart

Please check the images i used stack and positioned widget but the result is not responsive..
attached images are from two d/f emulators. please help.

Please check the images i used stack and positioned widget but the result is not responsive..
attached images are from two d/f emulators. please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdTyZ.png)

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
import 'package:imnci/credintials/contact_info.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoPageState createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(244, 245, 249, 1),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
       // overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[

          Positioned(
            height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
            left: -5,
            right: -5,
            top: -5,
            child: Card(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(109, 0, 252, 1.0),
              elevation: 0.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(40)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 330.0,
            right: 0.0,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
            top: 15,
            child: IconButton(
              color: Colors.white,
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
              onPressed: () {
                print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.19);
              },
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 16.0,
            right: 16.0,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.33,
            top: 70,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              ),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 50),
                        child: Text(
                          "Hi, Shah",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            letterSpacing: 3,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "What tou like to learn \n\ntoday!",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            letterSpacing: 1,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                      child: Center(
                        child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                          radius: 70.0,
                          animation: true,
                          animationDuration: 1200,
                          lineWidth: 3.0,
                          percent: 0.8,
                          center: new Text(
                            "75",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                          ),
                          circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          progressColor: Color.fromRGBO(109, 0, 252, 1.0),
                        ),
                      ))

                  /*  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [

                    ],
                  ),*/
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 45.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.19,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
            top: 35,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 16,
              shadowColor: Colors.yellow[700],
              color: Colors.yellow[700],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70, width: 0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/stetho.png",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
              left: 55.0,
              height: 1,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.81,
              top: 215,
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 1,
                color: Colors.grey,
              )),
          Positioned(
              left: 55.0,
              right: 10.0,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
              top: 230,
              child: Text(
                "5 CHAPTERS | 4 LESSONS",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
          Positioned(
              left: 30.0,
              right: 10.0,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.1,
              top: 280,
              child: Text(
                "Studying",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 295),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.4,
              child: new Swiper(
                  layout: SwiperLayout.CUSTOM,
                  customLayoutOption: new CustomLayoutOption(
                      startIndex: -1,
                      stateCount: 3
                  ).addRotate([
                    0.0/180,
                    00.0,
                    0.0/180
                  ]).addTranslate([
                    new Offset(-400.0, -0.0),
                    new Offset(-40.0, 0.0),
                    new Offset(270.0, -0.0)
                  ]),
                  itemWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width* 0.75,
                  itemHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.4,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new Card(
                      elevation: 1,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.2,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width* 0.8,
                            child: Image.asset("assets/card_doc.png",
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                          ),
                         Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, top: 18),
                         child: Text("Day 1",style: TextStyle(
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                           fontSize: 15,
                           color: Colors.grey[600],
                           letterSpacing: 1
                         ),)),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, top: 10, bottom: 30),
                              child: Text("Chapter #1",style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  letterSpacing: 1
                              ),),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //Center Row contents horizontally,

                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18),
                                child: Text("5 OF 8 LESSONS",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,letterSpacing: 1),),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.02,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.1,
                                  child: Card(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, width: 1),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60)),
                                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightGreenAccent,),
                                      value: 0.5,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                )
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],

                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 10,)
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
              left: 24.0,
              right: 20.0,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.1,
              top: 620,
              child: Card(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, right: 18, top: 8),
                          child: Text("Jump to current chapter",style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1),),),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18,top: 8),
                          child: Text("Chapter #1",style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1, fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),)
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, //Center Row contents horizontally,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                       children: [
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 66),
                          child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward), onPressed: () {  },)),
                      ],
                    )
                    ],
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the `SingleChildScrollView` up?

I mean, try to use `SingleChildScrollView` to wrap the `Scaffold` instead of the `Stack`.

Ps, I don't understand why you use Position to place all the element in a page... it's really hard to maintain, in my opinion...

Comment: what should be used in order to achieve this design if i remove the positioned widget?

Answer (score 0):

well [my emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVigv.jpg) does show any problems, but as i can see from the code the `SingleChildScrollView` is at the root and the over flow might be happening at the swipper child, i think the widgets dont have enough space `LinearProgressIndicator` and the text widget above it...u should check thoes

Comment: "i think the widgets dont have enough space LinearProgressIndicator and the text widget above it...u should check thoes"   what should i do if i want to keep these content as well in screen

Comment: if you check the second image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdTyZ.png 
there is one another widget as well